# Making series of buttons into an array ios

Tags: ios, arrays, uibutton

I have about 10-12 buttons that I'm adding to my scrollview. How can I make these into an array of buttons so that I can simplify the code? As of right now my code(only first three buttons are shown) is as follows:

```
    UIButton *redButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    redButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
    redButton.tag = 2;
    [redButton setTitle:@"red" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    redButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [redButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [redButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scollView addSubview:redButton];

    UIButton *blueButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    blueButton.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 50, 30);
    blueButton.tag = 3;
    [blueButton setTitle:@"blue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    blueButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [blueButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [blueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scollView addSubview:blueButton];

    UIButton *greenButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    greenButton.frame = CGRectMake(140, 0, 50, 30);
    greenButton.tag = 5 ;
    [greenButton setTitle:@"green" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    greenButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [greenButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [greenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scollView addSubview:greenButton];
```

...

Comment: You mean to store the buttons (so you're simplifying using them), or to configure them (then really you mean how do I write a loop to configure my buttons)?

Comment: Sorry,  yes,  I meant a loop to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see if this is possible

```
- (void)addButtonsToScrollView
{
    NSArray *buttons = @[@{@"Tag":@2,@"Title":@"red",@"Color":[UIColor redColor]},
                         @{@"Tag":@3,@"Title":@"blue",@"Color":[UIColor blueColor]},
                         @{@"Tag":@5,@"Title":@"green",@"Color":[UIColor greenColor]}];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    for (NSDictionary *dict in buttons)
    {
        UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = frame;
        button.tag = [dict[@"Tag"] integerValue];
        [button setTitle:dict[@"Title"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.backgroundColor = dict[@"Color"];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
        frame.origin.x+=frame.size.width+20.0f;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    contentSize.width = frame.origin.x;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:redButton,greenButton,blueButton,nil];
```

But might be better off using a NSDictionary

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                redButton, @"red",
                blueButton, @"blue",
                greenButton, @"green",
                nil];
```

That way you can use the key to look them up instead of index.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we have the solution, try this code mate,

[image]

```
-(void) createButtons{

    NSDictionary *buttonColors = @{@"Red":[UIColor redColor],@"Green":[UIColor greenColor],@"Black":[UIColor blackColor],@"Yellow":[UIColor yellowColor],@"Blue":[UIColor blueColor]};

    int tag = 1;
    for(NSString *key in buttonColors.allKeys){
        UIColor *color = [buttonColors objectForKey:key];
        UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(((tag -1)*70), 0, 50, 30);
        [button setFrame:frame];
        button.tag = tag;
        button.backgroundColor = color;
        [button setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [button setTitle:key forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

        tag++;
    }
}
```